# RecentlyViewed objects not returning Email... Sf bug?

Tags: bug

When I query the recentlyViewed object, the email address isn't being returned even though Email is a field that is supported per the documentation

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_recentlyviewed.htm
- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_recentlyviewed.htm).

**To reproduce:**

Run this query:

```
System.debug([SELECT Id, Email FROM RecentlyViewed]);
```

Response I receive (note that only the user object has an associated email):

```
12:20:12:182 USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|(RecentlyViewed:{Type=Lead, Id=00Qi0000007lWrmEAE}, RecentlyViewed:{Type=Lead, Id=00Qi000000BcsbtEAB}, RecentlyViewed:{Type=Lead, Id=00Qi000000BcRtHEAV}, RecentlyViewed:{Type=Lead, Id=00Qi000000BcRtHEAV}, RecentlyViewed:{Type=Topic, Id=0TOi0000000PTvGGAW}, RecentlyViewed:{Email=--!REDACTED!--, Type=User, Id=005i0000002seV7AAI}, RecentlyViewed:{Type=Topic, Id=0TOi0000000PW8oGAG}, RecentlyViewed:{Type=Topic, Id=0TOi0000000PW7bGAG}, RecentlyViewed:{Type=Report, Id=00Oi0000003vQAoEAM}, RecentlyViewed:{Type=Report, Id=00Oi0000003vQApEAM}, ...)
```

Is anyone else having this issue or am I doing something wrong? What's the best way to report it to Salesforce if it is a bug?

Comment: I have verified that the leads in question have values in their email fields.

Comment: This appears to be a bug, It looks like it should support querys..

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_recentlyviewed.htm